# How to show the places or Area boundaries in google map Android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, polygon

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEn7t.jpg)

I have searched for hours in the official maps docs and there was no clue how to add city boundaries in android google map. Its available for web in JavaScript https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/dds-boundaries/style-polygon#maps_boundaries_simple-javascript. but for android its not available. Is this possible in android some way?

I tried to Style a boundary polygon, data-driven style in map but didn't find anything useful.

Comment: Have you ever used GeoJSON file?
I think it's possible by using GeoJsonLayer that's created with geojson file.

Answer (score 1):

### Using a GeoJSON file to show area boundaries

As mentioned in the comment, using a GeoJSON file will make this possible, and you can do so by using the [Google Maps Android GeoJSON Utility](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/geojson).

as per the documentation:

> GeoJSON is an extension of the JSON data format and represents
> geographical data. Using this utility, you can store geographical
> features in GeoJSON format and render them as a layer on top of the
> map. To add and remove your GeoJSON data to and from the map, call
> `addLayerToMap()` and `removeLayerFromMap()` respectively. Similarly you
> can add and remove individual features by calling `addFeature()` and
> `removeFeature()` and passing in a GeoJsonFeature object. If you want to
> access the features, you can call `getFeatures()` to get an iterable of
> all GeoJsonFeature objects that have been added to the layer.

For example, we can use a GeoJSON file that contains a multi polygon of the boundary of USA called `usa.json` and save it to your `resource/raw` folder.

### usa.json

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "stroke": "#f53b3b",
        "stroke-width": 2,
        "stroke-opacity": 1,
        "fill": "#555555",
        "fill-opacity": 0.5
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [
                -124.45312499999999,
                48.22467264956519
              ],
              [
                -123.57421875,
                39.436192999314095
              ],
              [
                -120.32226562500001,
                34.45221847282654
              ],
              [
                -116.89453125,
                32.54681317351514
              ],
              [
                -114.873046875,
                32.69486597787505
              ],
              [
                -110.56640625,
                31.27855085894653
              ],
              [
                -108.720703125,
                31.50362930577303
              ],
              [
                -106.5234375,
                31.653381399664
              ],
              [
                -104.853515625,
                30.221101852485987
              ],
              [
                -103.095703125,
                29.152161283318915
              ],
              [
                -102.65625,
                29.6880527498568
              ],
              [
                -101.689453125,
                29.76437737516313
              ],
              [
                -97.294921875,
                25.799891182088334
              ],
              [
                -96.94335937499999,
                28.304380682962783
              ],
              [
                -93.779296875,
                29.458731185355344
              ],
              [
                -89.736328125,
                29.305561325527698
              ],
              [
                -88.76953125,
                30.372875188118016
              ],
              [
                -83.84765625,
                29.916852233070173
              ],
              [
                -81.298828125,
                25.3241665257384
              ],
              [
                -80.068359375,
                26.43122806450644
              ],
              [
                -82.001953125,
                30.977609093348686
              ],
              [
                -75.498046875,
                35.817813158696616
              ],
              [
                -73.564453125,
                40.84706035607122
              ],
              [
                -66.97265625,
                44.5278427984555
              ],
              [
                -68.5546875,
                47.21956811231547
              ],
              [
                -79.189453125,
                43.13306116240612
              ],
              [
                -83.3203125,
                41.83682786072714
              ],
              [
                -82.353515625,
                44.902577996288876
              ],
              [
                -88.24218749999999,
                47.81315451752768
              ],
              [
                -95.09765625,
                48.922499263758255
              ],
              [
                -124.45312499999999,
                48.22467264956519
              ]
            ]
          ],
          [
            [
              [
                -141.064453125,
                69.62651016802958
              ],
              [
                -152.9296875,
                70.64176873584621
              ],
              [
                -157.32421875,
                70.90226826757711
              ],
              [
                -166.376953125,
                68.43151284537514
              ],
              [
                -160.6640625,
                66.30220547599842
              ],
              [
                -164.53125,
                66.40795547978848
              ],
              [
                -168.22265625,
                65.62202261510642
              ],
              [
                -165.322265625,
                64.35893097894458
              ],
              [
                -161.19140625,
                64.66151739623564
              ],
              [
                -161.19140625,
                63.35212928507874
              ],
              [
                -164.53125,
                63.11463763252091
              ],
              [
                -166.11328125,
                61.60639637138628
              ],
              [
                -164.53125,
                60.71619779357714
              ],
              [
                -167.080078125,
                60.108670463036
              ],
              [
                -162.24609375,
                59.7563950493563
              ],
              [
                -161.806640625,
                58.63121664342478
              ],
              [
                -158.115234375,
                58.6769376725869
              ],
              [
                -168.3984375,
                52.908902047770255
              ],
              [
                -157.1484375,
                56.992882804633986
              ],
              [
                -153.80859375,
                56.70450561416937
              ],
              [
                -151.962890625,
                57.938183012205315
              ],
              [
                -148.7109375,
                60.19615576604439
              ],
              [
                -145.810546875,
                60.326947742998414
              ],
              [
                -140.9765625,
                60.1524422143808
              ],
              [
                -141.064453125,
                69.62651016802958
              ]
            ]
          ],
          [
            [
              [
                -160.20263671875,
                21.80030805097259
              ],
              [
                -159.63134765625,
                22.248428704383624
              ],
              [
                -159.30175781249997,
                22.14670778001263
              ],
              [
                -156.005859375,
                20.715015145512087
              ],
              [
                -154.75341796875,
                19.518375478601566
              ],
              [
                -155.76416015625,
                18.93746442964186
              ],
              [
                -156.02783203124997,
                19.766703551716976
              ],
              [
                -155.76416015625,
                20.076570104545173
              ],
              [
                -156.4892578125,
                20.591652120829167
              ],
              [
                -156.99462890624997,
                20.756113874762082
              ],
              [
                -158.115234375,
                21.37124437061831
              ],
              [
                -159.45556640625,
                21.820707853875017
              ],
              [
                -160.20263671875,
                21.80030805097259
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "title": "MultiPolygon United States of America"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you can create a function to retrieve the file from your resource folder like so:

```
    private void retrieveFileFromResource() {
        try {
            GeoJsonLayer layer = new GeoJsonLayer(getMap(), R.raw.usa, this);

            // this will be the function to add the layer on the map and 
            // I'll put it also below.
            addGeoJsonLayerToMap(layer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(mLogTag, "GeoJSON file could not be read");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(mLogTag, "GeoJSON file could not be converted to a JSONObject");
        }
    }
```

Then finally, add the layer on the map:

```
    private void addGeoJsonLayerToMap(GeoJsonLayer layer) {
        layer.addLayerToMap();
        // Demonstrate receiving features via GeoJsonLayer clicks.
        layer.setOnFeatureClickListener(new GeoJsonLayer.GeoJsonOnFeatureClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFeatureClick(Feature feature) {
                Toast.makeText(GeoJsonDemoActivity.this,
                        "Feature clicked: " + feature.getProperty("title"),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });
    }
```

It should look something like this:

[image: geoJSON boundary sample]

You can also clone the [android-maps-utils](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) library and play around with their GeoJSON samples.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help. but I need dynamically draw area boundaries and same are available in JavaScript provided by google map. and Trulia android app also did this functionality.